# How to access associateType value of property with type `any Protocol`

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `associatedType` in a protocol (`ChildProtocol`), in order to have a property (`parent`) that must conform to some other protocol (`ParentProtocol`). Now if I use the `ChildProtocol` like `var child: (any ChildProtocol)? = Child()` I cannot access the value `parent`, even though it must exist, since any `ChildProtocol` must have this value.

When just trying to access the parent, the compiler completely fails with:

> Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

I have created this simple code (MRE) to show this problem:

---

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ParentProtocol { }

protocol ChildProtocol {
    associatedtype anyParent: ParentProtocol
    var parent: anyParent { get set } // Any object should be allowed that conforms to ParentProtocol
}

class Parent: ParentProtocol { }

class Child: ChildProtocol {
    var parent = Parent()
}

class Test {
    
    var child: (any ChildProtocol)? = Child()
    
    func call() {
        if let parent = child?.parent { // doesn't compile
        }
    }
}
```

**edit** I have simplified the question and example to more clearly show the issue.

Comment: Do you need the associated type?  It works if I remove that and just have `var parent: any ParentProtocol { get set }` in `ChildProtocol`

Comment: Thanks for the response! In implementations of this protocol I am using explicit types. If I change the protocol to `any ParentProtocol` then I get `Type 'SomeClass' does not conform to protocol 'ChildProtocol` unless I just have the type of the property as `ChildProtocol`.

Comment: The type of which property?

Comment: You have to cast it to it’s actual type

Comment: Ooo this is just a compiler crasher. Could you please file a bug report?

Comment: @loremipsum I want to allow all types that conform to the protocol, so I do not know the type… Is it not possible without the specific type? I mean I know that whatever type it is, it must have the property, so why is there the need to specify the exact type? (Also, in the „simple case“ it works, without specifing the type)

Comment: @Alexander You are saying it should compile fine?

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry, in the code above the error would be „Type Child does not conform to protocol ChildProtocol“ if I have the property „parent“ as „Parent“. It works if I change the parent property to „ParentProtocol“

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated the question to be more on point.

Comment: It should either compile or give a proper error. If you expand the error in the build log you can see that the Swift compiler has crashed with "unhandled coercion"

Comment: The bug seems to be triggered by the optional chaining.  If you use an `if let unwrappedChild = child` to first unwrap `child` you can then say `unwrappedChild.parent` without crashing the compiler

Comment: @Paulw11 good catch, in this case that works. After my code still didn't compile I noticed that it was due to a `AnyObject` in the `ParentProtocol`. Since this wasn't originally part of this problem, I have opened a new question for it (see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77397107/how-to-use-associatedtype-in-protocol-conforming-to-anyobject) ). If you want, you can post this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted answer.