# How to use associatedType in protocol conforming to AnyObject

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

After my code stopped compiling I was able to break it down to simple issue:

**When using an `associatedType` that conforms to a protocol, which again conforms to `AnyObject` my code no longer compiles** not even giving a proper error:

> Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code

How can I make sure a `parent` property conforms to any object implementing a specific protocol that conforms to `AnyObject` (i.e. is a class)?

### Simple code example (MRE):

```swift
protocol ParentProtocol: AnyObject { // without AnyObject this runs fine
    var value: Int { get set }
}
protocol ChildProtocol: ParentProtocol {
    associatedtype parentType: ParentProtocol
    var parent: parentType! { get set }
}

class Test {
    var child: (any ChildProtocol)?
    
    func call() {
        if let child = child {
            print(child.parent.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does ChildProtocol extend ParentProtocol?

Comment: For me the code compiles as long as I don't access the `parent` property using `child.parent` inside the `call()` function (basically if you comment out the `print` statement it'll compile). Could be something got to do with resolving the type of `parentType`. I'll look into this in a while but I thought I'd share this with you just in case it helps

Comment: This seems like a compiler bug, I'd suggest [raising a bug report](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2C+triage+needed&projects=&template=bug_report.md&title=) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `ParentProtocol.parentType` to be an associated type ?

Your code compiles with :

```swift
protocol ChildProtocol: ParentProtocol {
    var parent: ParentProtocol! { get set }
}
```